# How can we exclude some data nodes only from one namespace in hdfs federation?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, namenode, datanode

I was checking the hadoop federation. Here the data nodes are common, only namespace will be different. How can we **exclude some datanodes only from one namespace**.

Answer (score 0):

In decommissioning the nodes that need to be decommissioned are added to the exclude file at all of the Namenodes. Each Namenode decommissions its Block Pool. When all the Namenodes finish decommissioning a Datanode, the Datanode is considered decommissioned.

For more details, you can have a look at: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html#Decommissioning

Comment: Dear Vin, as i mentioned i  want to remove a datanode from only one of the namenode not from both.

Comment: @Rahul As per my understanding, you can't do that because either that data node will be connected to the cluster or not. And if it is there in the cluster it should get updated in each namespace otherwise it violates the data  integrity

Answer (score 0):

You can just decommissioning a DataNode from one of the Namespace.